# Git Repository Only Gets Bigger After Using BFG

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

We are currently in the process of migrating our SVN repo to GIT (hosted at bitbucket).
I used subgit to import all our branches/history into a bare repo i have locally on my (Windows) PC.

The repo is quite big (7.42 GB after the import) this is because it also contains information about SVN like revision numbers to provide a way to have a two way sync between Git and SVN (I'm only interested in a one way SVN to GIT).

I create a local clone of the imported bare repo and push all the branches to bitbucket.
After a couple of hours (!) the repo was fully uploaded. BitBucket now gave me warnings about the repo size. I checked the size and it was 1.1GB. Thats not as big as the imported bare but still to big to have a fast repository.

After playing around with BFG i managed to remove soms large DLL/SQL export files using these commands on the bare repo (I only use the clone for pushing without all the svn-related refs):

```
java -jar bfg.jar --delete-files '{''specialized 2015''','''specialized,''insert-pcreeks''}.sql' --no-blob-protection

java -jar bfg.jar --delete-files 'Incara.*.dll' --no-blob-protection Incara.git

git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

This took a while and afterwards the git_find_big.sh script did not show these large sql files anymore. But after pushing things back to bitbucket (as a new repo, not as a force push) it only got bigger (1.8GB)

Can you provide a possible explanation for this behavior?

I don't know if it matters but we used a non standard branch/tag model in svn. This resulted in branches like:
`/refs/heads/archive/some/path/to/branch`. These branches seemed to work just fine and removing them also did not affect the size.

Next to these problems i noticed i had some XML files showing up in the `git_find_big.sh` output:

```
size,pack,SHA,location 12180,1011,56731c772febd7db11de5a66674fe6a1a9ec00a7 repository/frontend.xml 12074,1002,0cefaee608c06621adfa4a9120ed7ef651076c33 repository/frontend.xml 12073,1002,a1c36cf49ec736a7fc069dcc834b784ada4b6a06 repository/frontend.xml 12073,1002,1ba5bd92817347739d3fba375fc42641016a5c1d repository/frontend.xml 12073,1002,e9182762bfc5849bc6645fdd6358265c3930779f repository/frontend.xml 12073,1002,dff5733d67cb0306534ac41a4c55b3bbaa436a2e repository/frontend.xml 12072,1002,8ee628f645ce53d970c3cf9fdae8d2697224e64c repository/frontend.xml 12072,1002,1266dee72b33f7a05ca67488c485ea8afc323615 repository/frontend.xml
```

These files contain the frontend logic of the web platform we are using and are indeed quite big.
But they should be treated as text right? Therefore I don't get why they show up as separate objects in the above output. Am i right this should not be happening?

The SVN import also resulted in some empty commits (for example when SVN creates or moves a branch it needs a new commit). I guess these can only be removed using filter-branch?

Sorry, I have a lot of questions!
Could someone help me with this?

Thanks,

Piet

Comment: After the `git gc` step, how big is your local repo after cleaning? In particular, how big is the the objects/pack folder? Also, how big is a new local clone of your BitBucket repo?

Comment: Did you set up .gitignore to ignore SVN-related files? Maybe git and svn save each other's files?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: I did not change the .gitignore file. However subgit did create it and referenced some files that SVN already ignored. But I don't see any svn specific files in the git repo.

Comment: @RobertoTyley: 
After GC on clone: 2.15 GB (pack folder)

Clone from bitbucket: 1.33 GB (objects folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked for some more diagnostic information in comments on your question, which would be needed to give a reasonable answer to the main part, but as for your secondary questions (which Stackoverflow encourages you to ask separately, incidentally!), here are some pointers:

> Next to these problems i noticed i had some XML files showing up in
>   the git_find_big.sh output:
>   [snip]
>
> These files contain the frontend logic of the
>   web platform we are using and are indeed quite big. But they should be
>   treated as text right? Therefore I don't get why they show up as
>   separate objects in the above output. Am i right this should not be
>   happening?

Git allocates ids based on the contents of files (a SHA hash), and as far as that goes, doesn't care whether your files are text or not - if the files are even slightly different, their ids are different, and will be stored separately (Git *may* do delta compression under-the-hood, but this doesn't stop the files being defined as logically separate). So it's not surprising that different versions of the same file show up more than once in the `git_find_big.sh` output.

> The SVN import also resulted in some empty commits (for example when
>   SVN creates or moves a branch it needs a new commit). I guess these
>   can only be removed using filter-branch?

Yep, BFG doesn't do this out-of-the-box. However, it's one task that `filter-branch` *does* do reasonably quickly (even if it is fiddly to use).

Answer (score 1):

The pack sizing increase issue (after running BFG) resurfaced for me and ended up being due to git version 2.18 era version pack issues.  A coworker using 2.19 did not have the issue and I was able to find the bug fix description in 2.19.